# How can I cast base to a drived class?

Tags: java

Is there a work around that will allow me to cast an object of the base class to an object of the derived class?

something like the following

```
B extends A

A a = new A();
B b = (B)a
```

Is there a trick that will achieve this?

Comment: Did you mean `B extends A`? The current code would work fine, even without the explicit cast.

Comment: @JonSkeet yes that what I mean. I have edited the question

Comment: Polymorphism works when the reference variable is the parent and the object is a subclass. For example: Animal dog = new Dog();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, absolutely not. What would you expect the values of any fields declared in `B` but not in `A` to be? For example, what would you expect this to do:

```
Object x = new Object();
String text = (String) x;
System.out.println(text);
```

An `Object` has no text data... so what would it mean to cast it as a string?

You can only cast a reference to a type which is appropriate for the *actual* type of the object.

The desire to do this usually indicates a design problem somewhere... or it *might* mean that you want something like:

```
public class A {
    public A() { 
        // Whatever
    }

    public A(A a) {
        // Use the existing values in "a" to initialize this object
    }
}

public class B extends A {
    /** Creates a new B from the values in an A, with suitable defaults. */
    public B(A a) {
        super(a);
        // Now initialize any fields in B with appropriate values
    }
}
```

Then:

```
A a = new A();
B b = new B(a);
```

That will create two objects, unlike a cast... but it would at least be valid.

Answer (score 1):

How is that even possible? Think about it. It is like saying if you have a class `FourWheeler`, you can simply cast it into a `Ferrari` and make it a Ferrari!

Answer (score 0):

No, this isn't possible. When B extends A it inherits the behavior of A, but on the same time, there is nothing stopping you from defining new behavior for B (where those new behaviors won't be part of A)

For example say A has a single method called 'methodA'. Now when B extends A it inherits 'methodA' but it also declares another method called 'methodB'. So under such circumstance you will get a runtime 'ClassCastException' when you try to call the 'methodB' over an instance of Object A.